# SQL inner join with top 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I need to get table of latest known value one for each input.

I started with this

```
SELECT [MeterReadingId]
      ,[TimeStampUtc]
      ,[Val]
      ,[MeterReading].[InverterInputId]
      ,[Status]
  FROM [Project].[dbo].[MeterReading]
  inner join InverterInput on [MeterReading].InverterInputId = [InverterInput].InverterInputId
  inner join Inverter on [InverterInput].InverterId = [Inverter].InverterId 
  where [InverterInput].InputName = 'DayYield' and [Inverter].PlantId = 1
```

off course now i got all values which belong to inputs of name 'DayYield and plantId =1
My question is how can got table only of those values which have latest [TimeStampUtc]

Other words: get all those [Val] which belong to input of name  'DayYield and plantId =1 and are last inserted into table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this, you can use the [**ranking functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx), `ROW_NUMBER()` for example. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT [MeterReadingId]
          ,[TimeStampUtc]
          ,[Val]
          ,m.[InverterInputId]
          ,[Status]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.InverterInputId 
                             ORDER BY m.[TimeStampUtc] DESC) AS RN
      FROM [Project].[dbo].[MeterReading] AS m
      inner join InverterInput AS ii on m.InverterInputId = ii.InverterInputId
      inner join Inverter      AS i  on ii.InverterId     = i.InverterId 
      where ii.InputName = 'DayYield' and i.PlantId = 1
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Using `ORDER BY m.[TimeStampUtc] DESC` will give you the latest `[TimeStampUtc]` .

<strike>**Note that:** I don't know about the tables' structures you are using, but you might need to use another column to group by in the `PARTITION BY` clause instead of `MeterReadingId`.</strike>

Comment: I suppose that first word shouldb be WITH bu any way this query returns my all rows with all timestamps instead only the latest ones, and for query above WHERE RN = 1 is not needed, all rows have rn = 1

Answer (score 10):

One option is a `cross apply`, like:

```
select  *
from    Devices d
cross apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    Measurements m
        where   m.device_id = d.id
        order by
                m.timestamp desc
        ) m
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cross apply function far easier to read. It also means you maintain the basic structure of a normal query.

```
update cc
set cc.OutCC = oocd.CC, cc.Outcel = oocd.cel, 
    cc.Outcd = oocd.cd, cc.Outrn = oocd.rn, 
    cc.outidate = oocd.idate, cc.outtdate = oocd.tdate
from @CbC cc 
cross apply ( 
    select top 1 * from @OutC ocd
    where substring(ocd.rn,LEN(ocd.rn) - 9,9) = substring(cc.rn,LEN(cc.rn) - 9,9) and (ocd.cdate between cc.idate and DATEADD(hh,1,cc.idate)) and ocd.cdate < cc.tdate and ocd.cel like '%' + cc.line + '%' collate database_default  
order by ocd.idate
) oocd
```

Comment: It's not clear how this answer relates to the original question

Comment: @SvenHavgen It's not clear; What's a normal SQL structure? You might want to include a reference to the CROSS APPLY method you are recommending and an indication of how use of this function will help achieve the OP's objective of returning distinct results. (http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained)